# More elegant solution to multiple OR on same field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query that I want to select the values that contain either a `9` or `1` in the `event` field. This is working at the moment using the following expression:

```
event = 9 OR event = 1
```

Is there anyway I can cut this expression down? I've tried

`event = 9 OR 1`

but it seems to return everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
event in (1, 9, ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

`event IN (9, 1)` is what you're looking for